# Using sscanf to add an element to an int array per index

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

So, we have a "Machine Problem" where we are supposed to obtain the roots of a polynomial. My question is: Is there a way to add an element per index to an int array.

Here is my code(it's just a function btw)

```
void coeffunc(int degree){
     char coef[1000];
     int coefs[1000], i;

     printf("Enter %d integer coefficients starting from the 0th degree.\nSeparate each input by a comma: ", degree);
     fgets(coefs, 999, stdin);
     for(i=0;i!=degree;i++){
          sscan(coef, "%d[^,]", &coefs[i]);
     }
```

My problem with this code is I'm not sure how to catch an error if the input is a character.

Comment: `sscan(coef, "%d[^,]", &coefs[i]);` --> `if(sscanf(coef, "%d,", &coefs[i]) != 1){ /* Invalid input detected */ }`. Also, `fgets(coefs, 999, stdin);` --> `fgets(coefs, 1000 /* Or sizeof(coefs) */, stdin);`

Comment: To elaborate: `[s]scanf`returns the number of successfully read items (not chars), which can be 0 if no match was found, e.g. in your case no number was encountered before something else than white space. This return value (items, not chars) can actually be annoying because you don't know where in a string sscanf failed (so you cannot resume). Man pages for all things unix are online, just  google "man <function>".

Comment: I remembered that `[s]scanf` knows a `n` conversion which takes a pointer to int as corresponding parameter; the pointer is used to store the number of characters read so far which is the information missing from the return value.

Comment: `sscan(coef,` : 1st argument need update each loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use `"%n"` to save the count of scanned characters to know where to continue scanning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUFSIZE 1000

void coeffunc(int degree) {
  char coef[BUFSIZE];
  int coefs[BUFSIZE / 2];  // Number of integer certainly less than < BUFSIZE/2

  printf("Enter %d integer coefficients starting from the 0th degree.\n"
      "Separate each input by a comma: ", degree);
  if (fgets(coef, sizeof coef, stdin) == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  static const char *format[2] = { 
      "%d %n",
      " ,%d %n" };
  char *p = coef;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < degree; i++) {
    int n = 0;
    sscanf(p, format[i > 0], &coefs[i], &n);

    // Catch potential error 
    if (n == 0) break;

    p += n;
  }

  // More error detection
  if (*p) Fail();  // Extra text on the line
  if (i < degree) Fail(); // No enough values
}
```

---

Another buffer size approach if VLA allowed (Variable sized arrays)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
// bit_width*log10(2) rounded-up and sign
#define INT_TEXT_WIDTH (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 1 + 1)
// ", "
#define COMMA_SPACE 2
// \r\n\0
#define LINE_END 3
#define BUF_NEEDED(n) ((INT_TEXT_SIZE + COMMA_SPACE) * (n) + LINE_END)

void coeffunc(int degree) {
  int coefs[degree];
  // To cope with those who like lots of spaces, leading zeros, use a 2x buffer
  char coef[BUF_NEEDED(degree) *2];
  ...
```